# Regarding adb command: Error while loading shared libraries

Tags: adb, android-emulator

```
aneesh@nb-14:~$ adb devices
adb: error while loading shared libraries: libncurses.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I would like to understand the error above and correct it. This is just one instance, I get the same error on giving any adb command! Be it push, install, etc.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What distribution you are using? You might need to install the `libncurses5` package, it looks like.

Comment: It's already installed and is the latest version. Mine is Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit os.

Comment: So is mine, and here it works. See [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/JZMxTtSB) for details (updated). You probably lack the 32bit support, could that be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While `dpkg --add-architecture i386` command is not needed in the current version of Ubuntu (13.10), it is required in the current Debian versions (7.x) and it will be required in the future Ubuntu versions as well. So I am going to leave it in. Just ignore it for Ubuntu 13.10.

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get -qqy update
sudo apt-get -qqy install libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 zlib1g:i386
```

Update: `aapt` indeed requires `zlib` so I added it to the list. But you should not be needing any `lib32` packages.

Comment: There's no such package in Ubuntu 13.10

Answer (score 1):

@Izzy ,you are right.I hope this will solve the problem.

```
apt-get install ncurses-libs.i686 libstdc++.i686 libgcc.i686
```

Comment: There are no such packages on Ubuntu 13.10